# Laravel Split View and Controller into Different Host

Tags: laravel-5

I wish to break my app into 3 Tiers (UI, Business Logic, DB). Would it be possible to achieve this with Laravel? Means that, we reside the view codes in `host A` while placing the controller/model codes in `host B`. Could Laravel work in such way?

Comment: I don't see that you can separate Laravel views from the controllers and models that drive them. If you actually suggesting having a SPA or something, with a RESTful API, then yes that is possible.

Comment: Try Laravel lumen

Comment: Common approach is, one server is dedicated for API request serving web and app, and it only has controller/model and no view. Another server serves UI stuff only, and any auth / business logic are only proceeded through API requests.

Comment: Hi @Ben ... Thanks for your suggestion. Do you means able to use the Laravel API? Do anyone have the reference? Thanks a lot.